# I need to open PDF file in new window using angulat 10 or javascript. But I also need to change name pf the file before opening it

Tags: javascript, angular, openpdf

I'v tried to use this code (it seems to be posted everywhere):

```
const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
a.href = objectUrl
a.download = 'archive.zip';
a.click();
```

But it only downloads file. I need to change its name before opening.

Comment: you want to download or open?

Comment: I need open, like window.open(url, "_blank"). 
But before opening I need to change name of the file I want to open.

Answer (score 0):

Try using blob, as mentioned below.

```
const fileName = 'myFile';
const data = resp.body;
this.blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
var downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = downloadUrl;
link.download = fileName + '.pdf';
link.click();
```

Comment: seems that this aproach still makes the document to be downloaded with name: link.download = fileName + '.pdf';

I need to open it in new tab but set the name of it as I need